How do incorporate an OUTER APPLY function used in sql server when converting a query to SNOWFLAKE syntax
I have this script written in sql server syntax, that uses an OUTER APPLY. Seen below:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID, -- correct
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID, --correct
    s.Reference AS Shift,--correct
    c.BeginTime, -- correct
    c.EndTime, -- correct
    c.UpTime, -- wrong
    c.DownTime, --correct
    c.IdealInput, --wrong
    c.ActualInput, -- correct
    c.ActualOutput, -- wrong
    uom_base.Symbol AS BaseUoM,-- correct
    CAST(c.ActualOutput *
        CASE
            WHEN m.UnitOfMeasureID IN (m1.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) THEN 1
            ELSE from_muom.QuantityNumerator / from_muom.QuantityDenominator
        END *
        CASE
            WHEN uom_Operations.ID IN (m1.UnitOfMeasureID, m.UnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1
            ELSE to_muom.QuantityDenominator / to_muom.QuantityNumerator
        END AS DECIMAL) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM, --wrong
    uom_operations.Symbol AS OperationsUoM,
    c.RejectedOutput, -- wrong
    CASE WHEN s.Default_Capability_Type_ID = 'COMMITTED' THEN ps.IdealRunRate * (UpTime + DownTime) / 3600.0 ELSE 0 END AS ScheduledOutput, --wrong
    c.Failures, -- correct
    oreq.ExternalRef AS POnumber, --correct
    IFNULL(
        dateadd(
            HOUR,
            - (
                SELECT
                    DATE_PART(HOUR, MIN(s_first.FROM_TIME_OF_DAY))
                FROM
                    DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s_first
                WHERE
                    s_first.FROM_DAY = s.FROM_DAY
                    AND s_first.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID = s.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID
            ),
            dateadd(
                MINUTE,
                - (
                    SELECT
                        DATE_PART(MINUTE, MIN(s_first.FROM_TIME_OF_DAY))
                    FROM
                        DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s_first
                    WHERE
                        s_first.FROM_DAY = s.FROM_DAY
                        AND s_first.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID = s.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID
                ),
                c.BeginTime
            )
        ),
        dateadd(HOUR, - 6, c.BeginTime)
    ) :: DATE AS Production_Date
FROM calculation c
INNER JOIN DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s ON s.ID = c.ShiftID AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY, -31, CURRENT_DATE()) AND s.Default_Capability_Type_ID IN ('COMMITTED') -- why is 'AVAILABLE' here?
INNER JOIN Equipment e ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT JOIN EquipmentProperty ep ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID AND ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT JOIN JobOrder jo ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT JOIN WorkRequest wr ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
LEFT JOIN OperationsRequest oreq ON oreq.ID = wr.OperationsRequestID
LEFT JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT JOIN Material m ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
LEFT JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_base ON uom_base.ID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure from_muom ON from_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND from_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure to_muom ON to_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND to_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = uom_operations.ID
LEFT JOIN Material m1 ON m1.ID = m.ID
OUTER APPLY ( --
    SELECT top 1 IdealRunRate
    FROM PerformanceSpecification ps, equipment e,Material m
    WHERE ps.EquipmentID = e.ID AND
    (ps.MaterialID = m.ID 
        OR 
        (ps.MaterialID IS NULL AND 
        (ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID OR ps.MaterialClassID IS NULL)))
    ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN ps.MaterialID = m.ID THEN 2
            WHEN ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END DESC
) ps

when i try OUTER APPLY in snowflake, it does not work. I've read some places that you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN, but that does not work either. The columns that are not what i'm expecting are indicated with "wrong" and all the ones that use the IdealRunRate from the OUTER APPLY condition are impacted.
I found that Snowflake does not like it and from what i've read here, https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-rewrite-SQL-Server-OUTER-APPLY-queries-in-Snowflake i see i can write it as the following:
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT 
        c.ID AS CalculationID,
        e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
        s.Reference AS Shift,
        c.BeginTime,
        c.EndTime,
        c.UpTime,
        c.DownTime,
        c.IdealInput,
        c.ActualInput,
        c.ActualOutput,
        uom_base.Symbol AS BaseUoM,
        CAST(c.ActualOutput *
            CASE
                WHEN m.UnitOfMeasureID IN (m1.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) THEN 1
                ELSE from_muom.QuantityNumerator / from_muom.QuantityDenominator
            END *
            CASE
                WHEN uom_Operations.ID IN (m1.UnitOfMeasureID, m.UnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1
                ELSE to_muom.QuantityDenominator / to_muom.QuantityNumerator
            END AS DECIMAL) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM,
        uom_operations.Symbol AS OperationsUoM,
        c.RejectedOutput,
        CASE WHEN s.Default_Capability_Type_ID = 'COMMITTED' THEN ps.IdealRunRate * (UpTime + DownTime) / 3600.0 ELSE 0 END AS ScheduledOutput,
        c.Failures,
        oreq.ExternalRef AS POnumber,
        IFNULL(
            dateadd(
                HOUR,
                - (
                    SELECT
                        DATE_PART(HOUR, MIN(s_first.FROM_TIME_OF_DAY))
                    FROM
                        DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s_first
                    WHERE
                        s_first.FROM_DAY = s.FROM_DAY
                        AND s_first.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID = s.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID
                ),
                dateadd(
                    MINUTE,
                    - (
                        SELECT
                            DATE_PART(MINUTE, MIN(s_first.FROM_TIME_OF_DAY))
                        FROM
                            DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s_first
                        WHERE
                            s_first.FROM_DAY = s.FROM_DAY
                            AND s_first.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID = s.SHIFT_CALENDAR_ID
                    ),
                    c.BeginTime
                )
            ),
            dateadd(HOUR, - 6, c.BeginTime)
        ) :: DATE AS Production_Date
    FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.calculation c
    INNER JOIN DV_MFG_EU.vw_AAR_CPMS_SHIFT s ON s.ID = c.ShiftID AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY, -31, CURRENT_DATE()) AND s.Default_Capability_Type_ID IN ('COMMITTED')
    INNER JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.Equipment e ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.EquipmentProperty ep ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID AND ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.UnitOfMeasure uom_operations ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.JobOrder jo ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.WorkRequest wr ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.OperationsRequest oreq ON oreq.ID = wr.OperationsRequestID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.Material m ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.UnitOfMeasure uom_base ON uom_base.ID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.MaterialUnitOfMeasure from_muom ON from_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND from_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.MaterialUnitOfMeasure to_muom ON to_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND to_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = uom_operations.ID
    LEFT JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.Material m1 ON m1.ID = m.ID
), T2 AS (
    SELECT 
        T1.CalculationID,
        ps.IdealRunRate
    FROM T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ps.IdealRunRate,
            ps.EquipmentID,
            m.ID AS MaterialID,
            m.PrimaryMaterialClassID
        FROM RAW_CPMS_AAR.PerformanceSpecification ps
        INNER JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.equipment e ON ps.EquipmentID = e.ID
        INNER JOIN RAW_CPMS_AAR.Material m ON ps.MaterialID = m.ID OR (ps.MaterialID IS NULL AND (ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID OR ps.MaterialClassID IS NULL))
        ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN ps.MaterialID = m.ID THEN 2
                WHEN ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) ps ON ps.EquipmentID = T1.CalculationID
)

SELECT 
    T1.CalculationID,
    T1.SourceEquipmentID,
    T1.Shift,
    T1.BeginTime,
    T1.EndTime,
    T1.UpTime,
    T1.DownTime,
    T1.IdealInput,
    T1.ActualInput,
    T1.ActualOutput,
    T1.BaseUoM,
    T1.ActualOutputOperationsUoM,
    T1.OperationsUoM,
    T1.RejectedOutput,
    T1.ScheduledOutput,
    T1.Failures,
    T1.POnumber,
    T1.Production_Date,
    T2.IdealRunRate
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.CalculationID = T2.CalculationID;


however i'm getting another error in snowflake Error: invalid identifier 'PS.IDEALRUNRATE' (line 25). This is due to me referencing the performancespecification ps table within the query. I'm not quite sure how to get past that.

Have a look at Snowflake's LATERAL join.

Please give us sample data and desired results
